# Accessing elements from WebView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, webview

What is the simplest and most elegeant way to access elements of a web page in `WebView`? Also can we access elements that we know of such as search form on top of `stackoverflow` by its name when inspecting elements in browsers?

I read through some similar questions and answers about auto filling text fields from `jewelsea`, `James_D` and some other contributors but they all seem complicated to say at least.

I'll include short code where I createad a `WebView` and it would be nice if someone can fullfill this task in a simple and understandable way.

**Mail class**

```
public class Mail extends Region{
    final WebView webView = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

    public Mail() {
        webEngine.load("https://mail.metropolitan.ac.rs/?client=advanced#1");
        getChildren().add(webView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(mail, 0, 0, w, h, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }
```

**Method that adds `mail` to `StackPane`**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
private Mail mail;

// Unrelated code

@FXML
    private void selectMail() {
                mail = new Mail();
                stackPane.getChildren().add(mail);
            }
    }

// Unrelated code

}
```

And lets say that we want to access two TextFields to auto fill the form.

This is what I get after inspecting Username TextField:

`<input name="username" class="zLoginField" id="username" type="text" size="40" maxlength="1024" value="" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">`

And this is for Password TextField:

`<input name="password" class="zLoginField" id="password" type="password" size="40" maxlength="1024" value="" autocomplete="off">`

NOTE: This is not a task or something like that, I was just messing around with it so without any success. All examples are welcome, be it mine or yours.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [Document property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getDocument--) of WebEngine.

To access your input fields:

```
Element inputField = webEngine.getDocument().getElementById("username");
inputField.setAttribute("value", "New Text");
```

For something like the Stack Overflow search form, you can use XPath to find the Element:

```
Element inputField = (Element)
    XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate(
        "//*[@id='search']//*[@name='q']",
        webEngine.getDocument(),
        XPathConstants.NODE);
inputField.setAttribute("value", "New Text");
```

**Update based on comment:**  To set a field while the page is still loading, you can attempt to set it as the WebEngine updates its loadWorker:

```
public class HtmlInputSetter
extends Application {
    private static final String NEW_TEXT = "NullPointerException";

    private WebView webView;

    private boolean fieldsHaveBeenSet;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().progressProperty().addListener(
            (o, old, progress) -> updateFields());

        fieldsHaveBeenSet = false;
        webView.getEngine().load("http://stackoverflow.com");

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(webView);
        pane.setPrefWidth(1200);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.setTitle("HTML Input Setter");
        stage.show();
    }

    private void updateFields()
    {
        Document doc = webView.getEngine().getDocument();
        if (doc != null && !fieldsHaveBeenSet) {
            try {
                Element inputField = (Element)
                    XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate(
                        "//*[@id='search']//*[@name='q']",
                        doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
                if (inputField != null) {
                    inputField.setAttribute("value", NEW_TEXT);
                    fieldsHaveBeenSet = true;
                }
            } catch (XPathException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you make a small example how to fill the fields while the web page is loading? I'd really appreciate it.